# I am having some trouble using variables from one class in my driver class

Tags: java, string, hashcode, println

Hi sorry if this is a stupid question I've just been very stuck on it.
I am trying to create new users in my driver class as well as check to see if the password is valid and deactivate the accounts.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Also a point in the right direction or an example of a similar code would be great. I'm not just looking for the answer, but I want to understand why..

Thanks in advance if you will read all this! (:

This is my class where I created the variables.

**Updated Code**
Alright so I went back and made some changes (updated code above) The username, password and active status are appearing as I wanted them to.  How can I make the accounts active by default? I also can't figure out how to write the deactivateAccount method so that it changes to false

```
private String username;
private String password;
private boolean active;

    public UserAccount() {
        active = true;
    }

    public UserAccount(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean checkPassword(String password) {
         if (this.password.equals(password)) {
         return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public void deactivateAccount(String username){
        username = this.username;
        active = false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return username + password + active;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((username == null) ? 0 : username.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof UserAccount))
            return false;
        UserAccount other = (UserAccount) obj;
        if (username == null) {
            if (other.username != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!username.equals(other.username))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

**This is the Driver Class**

public class UserDriver {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserAccount user1 = new UserAccount("  Rachel  ", "Birthday  ");
        UserAccount user2 = new UserAccount("  Brandi  ", "Purple  ");



        System.out.println("User 1: " + user1);
        System.out.println("User 2: " + user2);

        if (user1.equals(user2)) {
            System.out.println("The users are equilvalent");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The users are not equivilent");
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: If you're having questions about error messages, please post the full message. Makes sense, no?

Comment: Your question is not clear or it is absent. Please be very clear about what you want to ask.

Comment: Sorry This is the error I am getting. I am trying to create a new username Rachel and set the password as Birthday.  They don't have to be these things they can just be examples.  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Rachel cannot be resolved to a variable
 Birthday cannot be resolved to a variable              
 Brandi cannot be resolved to a variable
 Purple cannot be resolved to a variable
 password cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing in Strings but rather undeclared variables. Change

```
UserAccount user1 = new UserAccount(Rachel, Birthday);
UserAccount user2 = new UserAccount(Brandi, Purple);
// What are the Rachel, Birthday, Brandi and Purple?
```

to

```
UserAccount user1 = new UserAccount("Rachel", "Birthday"); // ah now they're Strings!
UserAccount user2 = new UserAccount("Brandi", "Purple");
```

In the future, if you need to ask questions about compilation errors or thrown exceptions, please post the full message for us to evaluate. Otherwise you force us to guess which is no fun.

Comment: Thank you! I am so sorry I am new at this. Do you know how I would call the toString method from the system.out.println in my driver program?

Comment: @CeraOrtega: The `System.out.println(...)` method automatically calls the `toString()` method of any object passed into it.

Comment: When I put System.out.println(user1); I get UserAccount [getClass()=class Assignment1.UserAccount, hashCode()=-1058640628, toString()=Assignment1.UserAccount@c0e66d0c]

Comment: @cerasaurus: that **is** the `toString()` result returned from the UserAccount class.

Answer (score 0):

`if (password.equals(password))` compares the passed parameter against itself.

Try `if (password.equals(this.password))`

Comment: Yep, this is happening. checkPassword(String password) shadows the password variable belonging to UserAccount. Another fix would be to rename the password parameter to something like "aPassword" or even just "value", and in general try to pick better variable names to avoid shadowing.

Answer (score 0):

Will these compile the first thing

```
UserAccount user1 = new UserAccount(Rachel, Birthday); 
UserAccount user2 = new UserAccount(Brandi, Purple);
```

As `public UserAccount(String username, String password)` takes String arguments

Then why this

```
System.out.println(user1.toString());
System.out.println(user2.toString());
```

it will just print the hash of the objects

Then `user1.checkPassword(password);` what is password now I cannot see any declaration or initialization over there suppose you have initialized it then the call goes to

```
public boolean checkPassword(String password)
```

It is confused again because your name for the local variable conflicts with the instance variable to avoid it just use this keyword on the instance variable
Like

```
if (this.password.equals(password)){//do this}
```